# What is the difference between "out of" and "of"

Tags: prepositions, difference

I saw this sentence in a grammar book.

- *Who is the youngest girl **of** the three.*

But I think that I can change **of** to **out of** without changing the meaning. Is it true? Please tell me.

Comment: Just "of" is idiomatic.  Changing it to "out of" (or "from among") would still be technically correct, but a little clunky and not typical.

Answer (score 2):

All of these are quite commonly heard in AmE:

> She is the youngest of the three.
>
> She is the youngest girl of the three.
>
> She is the youngest out of the three.
>
> She is the youngest girl out of the three.

In this particular usage, **out of** is the more colloquial/informal, so while it is heard fairly often it would be far less likely to appear in expository writing.

Answer (score 0):

In this context both prepositions are correct and interchangeably, however, "Yes!", **of** sounds idiomatic.

["**girl out of the three**"](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22girl%20out%20of%20the%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=8t83WeeaAeKn6ATY05P4DA#q=%22girl%20out%20of%20the%20three%22&newwindow=1)

["**girl of the three**"](https://www.google.ru/search?q=one%20out%20of%20a%20group%2C%20one%20of%20a%20grop&oq=one%20out%20of%20a%20group%2C%20one%20of%20a%20grop&aqs=chrome..69i57.15543j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=%22girl%20of%20the%20three%22)