# When to use 'out of' and 'of'?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I am asking this in the context of a sentence: "Why to pick this packet on the shelves of many?" Should it be 'on the shelves of many' or 'on the shelves out of many'? The second option is suggested by my English tutor. It is a sentence from a commercial and humorous write-up on the back of a food packaging

Comment: When it refers to the relationship between a larger group (***many** [shelves]*, here) and some "subset" thereof (one or several items; ***this packet***, here), we usually include *both* prepositions when we want to focus on the sense of ***extracted, taken from** [the larger set]*. As opposed to, say, *John is one **of** my children*, where the single preposition ***of*** primarily indicates "membership of group" rather than "abstraction from [larger, containing] group".

Comment: ***...Out of** all my children, John is the one I worry about most*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some usages like this case, out of is the more colloquial/informal, so while it is heard fairly often it would be far less likely to appear in writing. Plus your sentence is grammatically wrong, it should be

> why pick this packet [out of/of] the many (others)?

But otherwise both are fine.

You can read more [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131759/what-is-the-difference-between-out-of-and-of)

Comment: @DialForest Yes, it won't be 'why to pick'. The sentence mentioned is written in this way because it means that there are many brands' packets of the same product, and out of them, why should you buy this or pick this packet.

Comment: @user324713 i edited my answer, does it help? (Sorry i got confused about the shelf)